# mysql database not working on django

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-module

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
    'NAME': 'djangodb',             
    'USER': 'root',                 
    'PASSWORD': '',                 
    'HOST': '',                    
    'PORT': '',                      
} 
  }
```

I created a database djangodb now I 
tried creating tables
with this command

```
./manage.py syncdb
```

I expected to get

```
Creating table auth_message
Creating table auth_group
Creating table auth_user
Creating table auth_permission
Creating table django_content_type
Creating table django_session
Creating table django_site
Creating table blog_blogpost
```

But I get this error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading  MySqldb module: no module named MySqldb
```

I have even tried putting up a host 127.0.0.1 .Can anyone figure out what happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you installed MySQL-python?

```
pip install mysql-python
```

Answer (score 1):

From [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/install/#get-your-database-running):

> If you're using MySQL, you'll need the `MySQL-python` package, version 1.2.1p2 or higher. You will also want to read the database-specific notes for the MySQL backend.